# Can a blocked thread fire events?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, autoresetevent

I have a program that spawns a thread controlling a serial communication. While it waits for response on the serial port, I block the thread with a AutoResetEvent.

*Will that thread be unable to execute the event when data is received because it is blocked?*

To illustrate the point I have a simple version of my code below. Will this code result in a deadlock or can an event run in a blocked thread, eventually waking up itself?

```
AutoResetEvent rxDataReady = new AutoResetEvent(false);

public void GetSomeDataFromSerialPort()
{
    SerialPort sp = new SerialPort()
    sp.Write(dataRequest)

    rxDataReady.WaitOne();

    // Process data
}

private void ReadDataEventHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    // Prepare data
    rxDataReady.Set();
}
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The remarks from MSDN [SerialPort.DataReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The DataReceived event is raised on a **secondary** thread when data is received from the SerialPort object

So I don't think your code sample will end up deadlocking.

However, the answer to your question in the title:

> Can a blocked thread fire events?

No.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in the title: No. A blocked thread cannot raise an event.
However, if a different thread is responsible for raising the event, it should work as expected.

To illustrate this, here's an example:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static readonly AutoResetEvent RxDataReady = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    private static event EventHandler ev;

    public static void GetSomeDataFromSerialPort()
    {
        RxDataReady.WaitOne();

        // Process data
    }

    private static void Main()
    {
        ev += ReadDataEventHandler;
        Task.Run(
            async () =>
                {
                    await Task.Delay(5000);
                    ev(null, EventArgs.Empty);
                });
        GetSomeDataFromSerialPort();

        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void ReadDataEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        // Prepare data
        RxDataReady.Set();
    }
}
```

What this code does is simply start a new thread that waits for 5 seconds and then raises an event.
If you try running this, you'd see that after 5 seconds "Done." is displayed in the console.

If you were to raise the event on the same thread:

```
 private static void Main()
    {
        ev += ReadDataEventHandler;
        GetSomeDataFromSerialPort();
        ev(null, EventArgs.Empty);

        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Then the event will never be raised, and execution will never continue beyond `RxDataReady.WaitOne()`.

An alternative to this would be to run `GetSomeDataFromSerialPort()` on a different thread.

Comment: @Diryboy answer is better as it is regarding SerialPort.DataReceived specifically where I give a more general answer.